# ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails That I can't fix

Tags: python, mysql, foreign-keys

I am getting this error :

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint 
fails (\`GTFS\`.\`#sql-37d_16\`, CONSTRAINT \`#sql-37d_16_ibfk_1\` FOREIGN KEY 
(\`service_id\`) REFERENCES \`calendar\` (\`service_id\`))
```

I'm trying to create my database tables with python , this is what i've tried :

```
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routes(route_id  varchar(3) PRIMARY KEY, agency_id varchar(2) ,route_short_name varchar(20) ,route_long_name varchar(50) ,route_desc varchar(30) ,route_type varchar(30) ,route_url varchar(30) ,route_color varchar(30) ,route_text_color varchar(30)) ")

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calendar (service_id varchar(4) PRIMARY KEY,monday varchar(4) ,tuesday varchar(4) ,wednesday varchar(4) ,thursday varchar(4) ,friday  varchar(4) ,saturday varchar(4) ,sunday varchar(4) ,start_date varchar(8) ,end_date varchar(8)) ")

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trips (route_id varchar(3) ,service_id varchar(4) ,trip_id varchar(6) PRIMARY KEY,trip_headsign varchar(20) ,trip_short_name varchar(3) ,direction_id varchar(1) ,block_id varchar(1) ,shape_id varchar(5) )")

mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE trips ADD FOREIGN KEY (service_id) REFERENCES calendar(service_id); ")

mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE trips ADD FOREIGN KEY (route_id) REFERENCES routes(route_id); ")
```

I'm expecting to insert into my table some data provided in a list but i always get this error in my terminal

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & then read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some values for `trips.service_id` column don't exist in the parent(`calendar`) table for the common column `service_id`.

You may try to insert those values by such a insert statement :

```
insert into calendar(...,service_id,...) 
select ...,service_id,... 
  from trips t
 where not exists ( select 0 from calendar where service_id=t.service_id );
```

before adding the constraint by

`ALTER TABLE trips ADD FOREIGN KEY (service_id) REFERENCES calendar(service_id);`

Comment: thank but i'm using a table to insert data into my table . tup=(l[i][0],l[i][1],l[i][2],l[i][3],l[i][4])
 sql = "INSERT INTO shapes (shape_id ,shape_pt_lat ,shape_pt_lon ,shape_pt_sequence ,shape_dist_traveled) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
 mycursor.execute(sql, tup)
 mydb.commit()

Comment: you're welcome @MohamedAmineBENABDALLAH that's not related with your current insert statement in the code, but you can run the insert statement in the answer to fix the foreign-primary mutual relations before running your code. I mean fix the data first of all.